# globalkey formstate return false when validation

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in Flutter and i am trying to create sign-in form validation and use this [FadeIndexedStack](https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/1cd23e79a31d0c18a67424f0cbdfd7ad). but always get false when i call *formKey.currentState.validate()*. formKey is global key form state

1. the form looks like this:
   [form stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8606T.png).
2. the textformfield is like this:

```
Container( //container textformfield (inside fadeindexedstack)
 //rest code

 TextFormField(
  validator: (val) => val.length < 3 ? ' too short.' : null,
  onChanged: (String value) {
   username = value;
  },
 ),
 TextFormField(
  validator: (val) => val.length < 3 ? ' too short.' : null,
  onChanged: (String value) {
   password = value;
  },
 ),

 //rest code
)
```

3. the button which returns validate:

```
FlatButton( //outside fadeindexedstack
 onPressed: () {
   print(formKey.currentState.validate());
 }
```

how do i get *true* value for validation?

Comment: Hi, What value did you entered into your textfield ?

Comment: @ikerfah it's String username and String password

Comment: The validation will become true if your fields are filled in and fulfil the validation you defined. Are you testing it with the fields filled?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes, i already test it, it returns  ' too short.'  when the values don't meet the requirement but when i test it with a value which fulfills the requirement it's return null but the validate still return false

Comment: Can you please show us both the text fields code ?

Comment: @ikerfah updated post. actually it's basically the same, i believe it's not because the textformfield because when i put container outside FadeIndexedStack it's working

Comment: In this case of having textfield inside ```IndexedStack``` i prefer to use a form for each child of the stack. and then in the button it will be something like this : ```keys[_count].currentState.validate()```. the idea is having multiple nested Form for each child instead of global form.

Comment: @RudiSetiawan if it helped i can post it as an answer for others too

Comment: yes, you can post it as an answer